# Structure returning function

Tags: c

In *C* component selection, what is the benefit of structure-returning function? for example:

```
struct S {
   int a, b;
} x;
```

Why is it that I can assign the above struct as a function as shown below, Is there any benefit of doing this?

```
extern struct S f(); /* Why is this neccesary? */
x = f(); /* Is this accurate */
```

Open my eyes on this guys.

Comment: It is not clear that you are asking here...

Comment: Here's a similar question for defining the signature of function that would like to return more than one variable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8999520/143897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a function that happens to return a `struct`. There's nothing more to it than that. You wouldn't be surprised to see a function return an `int`, why be surprised when one returns a struct?

As an aside, the `extern` is superfluous here because that is the default storage class for functions.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful so that you can return multiple values from a function.

For example, you can use it like this

```
struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
};

struct Point getMousePos()
{
    struct Point pos;
    pos.x = 567;
    pos.y = 343;
    return pos; 
}

int main()
{
    struct Point mouse_pos = getMousePos();
    printf("Mousepos %d,%d\n", mouse_pos.x, mouse_pos.y");   
}
```

The function can be forward declared with `extern` (this would normally be done in a header file), so that other functions know its prototype i.e. its parameters and return type, even if the function is itself defined in another file.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a copy of a struct instead of a pointer to it, you know that you never have to worry about `free()`ing it, or whether there are any data races where one thread is writing to the struct while another reads from it, or whether the pointer returned by the function will be invalidated by some action that might be outside of your control.